# Question on existence of a symmetric matrix

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $ A $ be an $n\times n$ matrix with real entries. Then is it always possible to find a  real symmetric $n \times n$  matrix $B$ such that $B^ 2$ = $A \times A.$?

It would be great if someone could give me some hints.I am currently reading linear algebra

Comment: Do you assume that $A$ is also symmetric

Comment: No ,No sir I dont assume it @orangeskid

Comment: Is $A\times A$ just $A \cdot A$ ?

Comment: yes you are right

Comment: Why not write $B^2=A^2$ then?

Answer (score 2):

Note that if $B$ is symmetric, then $B^2$ is also symmetric. Therefore, if $A^2$ is not symmetric, there exists no such $B$.

The condition really is :such $B$ exists if and only if $A^2$ symmetric and the eigenvalues of $A$ are real. That will make $A^2$ positive semi-definite, and for these there exists a square root $B$ symmetric (even positive semi-definite).

Therefore: two checks: $A^2$ symmetric and eigenvalues of $A$ real.

Comment: is the condition that $A$ has either real or purely imaginary eigenvalues sufficient for $A^2$ to be symmetric?

Comment: @abel No; for instance
$$
A =
\left( \begin{array}{cc}
1 & 1 \\
0 & 1 \end{array} \right).
$$

Comment: @mollyerin, thanks. do you know of a sufficient condition for $A^2$ to be symmetric but $A$ is not.

Comment: @abel Not offhand; maybe post it as a Math:SE question? :D

Answer (score 0):

**Hint**

If this was true then $B^{T}=B$. Which means $A^{2}=[A^{T}]^{2}$. Now try to see if you can find a matrix $A$ which might not follow this last condition. Try with $2 \times 2$ examples.

Comment: yes will this do ? @Anurag A

Comment: a_11=0,a_12=1,a_21=2,a_22=1

Comment: are u there ?@ Anurag

Answer (score 0):

If $A$ be a symmetric matrix then the problem will be solved.Let $A=\left( \begin{array}{cc}
1 & 1 \\
0 & 0 \end{array} \right)$ then $A^2=\left( \begin{array}{cc}
1 & 1 \\
0 & 0 \end{array} \right)$ but if $B=\left( \begin{array}{cc}
a & b \\
b & c \end{array} \right)$ be a symmetric matrix then $B^2=\left( \begin{array}{cc}
a^2+b^2 & ab+bc \\
ab+bc & b^2+c^2 \end{array} \right)$ imply $b=c=0$ and $a=1$. this is an counterexample for above problem.

Comment: so u have got  a symmetric matrix .what' s your point

Comment: For $A$ anti-symmetric there will in general not be a symmetric solution $B$ to $B^2=A^2$.